# RecyclerView resizes ExpandableTextView when it's opened

Tags: android, textview, adapter, android-recyclerview

I use this awesome library:
github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView
to create ExpandableTextView for `RecyclerView` items, but there is something wrong when I open item and then scroll up - items, which has less then 4 lines (ExpandableTextView expands on >4 lines) become very height.

My screenshots:
[Normal item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akrPk.png)
[After opening expanding another item and scrolling up to this item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqSBi.png)